# PHP mail() not sending email - small error somewhere

Tags: php, email

I can't see the error in my code - the if statement echoes 'no' but all the variables are correct

```
$to = 'mail@mail.com';
  $subject = $job.' - '.fetchtitle();
  $message = 'Name: '.$_POST['fname'].' '. $_POST['surname'].'<p>
              Address: '. $_POST['address'].', '. $_POST['city'].', '. $_POST['postcode'].'<p>
              Phone: '. $_POST['phone'].'<p>
              Email: '. $_POST['email'].'<p>
              Cover Letter: '. $_POST['covletter'];

  mail($to, $subject, $message);
  if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
    echo 'Sent!';
  else echo 'no';
```

Comment: *"small error somewhere"* => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and this `mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  if(mail($to, $subject, $message))
    echo 'Sent!';` why are you using `mail()` twice and the same variables?

Comment: To see if that was the error, I'll have a look at the link

Comment: Your `html` seems strangely formed and you will need the `HTML` header.